# Как переделать меню?

Tags: html, css

Хочу переделать меню сайта, как на сайте midiltd.ru (Cлева), чтобы при наведении на  категорию выдвигались подменю.
Вот код меню, который стоит на сайте.

```css
#left_block{
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.one_block{
 width: 100%;
 //border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #efefef;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.block_head{
 padding: 5px 0 0px 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #00007F;
}

.block_body{
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li.menu_catalog{
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 color: black;
}

ul.menu{
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
}

li.menu{
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 50px;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-weight:normal;
}

a.menu, a.menu_curr{
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu_catalog{
 padding-top: 10px;
}


li.menu_catalog{
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 color: black;
}

li.menu:hover, li.menu_curr{
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

li.menu_catalog:hover, li.menu_child_catalog:hover, li.menu_curr_catalog{
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
}

a.menu_catalog, a.menu_curr_catalog, a.menu_child_catalog{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a.menu_catalog{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="left_block">
    
    <div class="one_block">
     <div class="block_head">
      Каталог товаров
     </div>
     <div class="block_body">
      <div class="catalog">
       <div id="menu_catalog">
 <ul class="menu_catalog">
 <li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Китай</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Япония</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Африка</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Австралия</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">США</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Омск</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Саратов</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Самара</a></li>
<li onclick="el = document.getElementById('parent140'); el.style.display = (el.style.display=='none')?'block':'none';" class="menu_catalog">Тепло</li>
<ul class="menu_parent" id="parent140" style="display: none;"><li onclick="el = document.getElementById('parent123'); el.style.display = (el.style.display=='none')?'block':'none';" class="menu_catalog">- Москва</li>
<ul class="menu_parent" id="parent123" style="display: none;"><li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Россия</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#j" class="menu_catalog">Города</a></li>
</ul>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">- Дома</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Самолеты</a></li>
</ul>
<li onclick="el = document.getElementById('parent119'); el.style.display = (el.style.display=='none')?'block':'none';" class="menu_catalog">Вертолеты</li>
<ul class="menu_parent" id="parent119" style="display: none;"><li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Лодки</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Мотоциклы</a></li>
<li class="menu_catalog"><a href="#" class="menu_catalog">Машины</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Меню сайта, как на сайте, стоит на сайте. Проясните, пожалуйста, всю эту вязь сайтов. Вы хотите переделать тот код, который Вы показали здесь, чтобы имел похожий функционал, как на сайте midiltd.ru (Cлева)?

Comment: залог успешного кода заключается в его минимизации и простоте, увы, при просматривании кучи лишних классов у элементов возникает некий отдалённый испанский стыд :<

Comment: Да я хочу меню как у midiltd.ru , но с моим html кодом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  max-width: 330px;
}

.menu li {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.submenu {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(20px);
  transition: transform .3s ease, opacity .4s ease;
}

.menu li:hover .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu > li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А можно без изменения html кода?

Comment: Принцип решения для вашегй разметки тот же что и в примере

Comment: как вариант вместо **прятания** элемента можно его полностью скрыть с 
 помощью visibility

Comment: MoloF - не вижу в этом проблемы,  используйте тот вариант который вам необходим (display;none, visibility:hidden, scale(0))

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то Вам нужно, чтобы при на ведении на один список выпадал другой?
В таком случае можно разместить один список внутри другого и скрыть его через `display:none;`, а затем задать `display:block;` при наведении на элемент списка, внутри которого находится скрытый список.

Comment: ну мне нужно меню как у midiltd.ru